# How to isolate a Galera node for update?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I’m setting up new hosting for a client who is currently with one of the large hosting companies.  The new setup includes three Lamp stack servers, A, B and C.  Server A will be the live server, with B and C as failover backups.  MariaDB servers are set as Galera nodes.

Currently, the client uploads txt files a couple times a day to update the database.  The update software deletes the contents of about 10 tables and inserts current data from the txt files. In the current setup, this only takes a few seconds, but when this upload is performed on the new setup, it takes about 10 minutes to complete.  During this time, Server A is down.

I’m quite sure this is because Galera inserts one row at a time, and completes this single insertion across all three servers before inserting the next.

If I shut down MySQL on Servers B and C, the update is completed quite quickly.  So I think I need to isolate Server A by either shutting down MySQL on Servers B and C, or isolate Server A in some other way.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.